# Rearrange unique HashMap values in HashMap<String[]> or HashMap<ArrayList>

Tags: hashmap

In my table, I've datas as follow,

**Username Age**
Anvar       26
Ragul 25
Prabhu  26
Praveen 25
Siva    26
Imran   26
Rajkumar    25
Vinoth  24

Here I want to categorize the username according to their ages and to store it in a string array, currently I've coded as below and it's working fine. **But I want simplify it. If anyone have better any idea, please share.** Thanks

```
package test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class Options {

    static String URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample;create=true";
    static String USER = "admin";
    static String PASS = "admin";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        HashMap<String,Integer> allValue = new HashMap<String,Integer> (); 
        HashMap<Integer,String> uniqValue = new HashMap<Integer,String> ();
        HashMap<Integer,String[]> newMap = new HashMap<Integer,String[]> ();

        String name[] =null;

        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from userDetails");  

            while(rs.next()){  
                allValue.put(rs.getString(1), rs.getInt(2));
                uniqValue.put(rs.getInt(2), rs.getString(1));
            } 

            Iterator uniqEntries = uniqValue.entrySet().iterator();

            while (uniqEntries.hasNext()) {
                int j=0;
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) uniqEntries.next();
                Integer key = (Integer)entry.getKey();
                String value = (String) entry.getValue();

                Iterator allEntries = allValue.entrySet().iterator();
                name = new String[5];
                    while (allEntries.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry allentry = (Map.Entry) allEntries.next();
                        String allkey = (String)allentry.getKey();
                        Integer allvalue = (Integer) allentry.getValue();

                            if(key == allvalue){
                                name[j] = allkey;   
                                j++;
                            }
                    }
                    newMap.put(key, name);
            }

             Iterator newEntries = newMap.entrySet().iterator();
                while (newEntries.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry newentry = (Map.Entry) newEntries.next();
                    Integer newkey = (Integer)newentry.getKey();
                    String[] newValue = (String[])newentry.getValue();

                    System.out.println("Age "+newkey);
                    for(int n=0;n<5;n++){
                        if(newValue[n] != null){
                            System.out.println("User "+newValue[n]);    
                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("\n");                       
                }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output :

Age 25
User Rajkumar
User Praveen
User Ragul

Age 24
User Vinoth

Age 26
User Anvar
User Imran
User Siva
User Prabhu

Comment: what exactly do you want to simplify? Reduce lines of code, make it more readable, optimace performance...

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to first, order the results retrieved from the database by `age`.

```
    rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from userDetails order by age desc");
```

Then, have a map, `values`, with a mapping between the age and the list of users for that age.

```
    Map<Integer,List<String>> values = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>();
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    int prevAgeGroup = -1;
    int currentAgeGroup = 0;
    while(rs.hasNext())
    {
        currentAgeGroup = rs.getInt(2);
        if(currentAgeGroup != prevAgeGroup && prevAgeGroup > -1)
        {
            values.put(prevAgeGroup, names);
            names = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        names.add("user "+rs.getString(1));
        prevAgeGroup = currentAgeGroup;
    }
    values.put(currentAgeGroup, names);
```

The above code, iterates each entry from the database and since all the entries would be ordered by age, we can sequentially check if the current age is different from the last encountered age. If it is, create a new list for storing the list of users for the current age.

You can also have a look into [MultiHashMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html), to achieve this functionality in a simpler way.